# Firebase Firestore trigger for document create after delay

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am using firebase firestore database and firebase functions. The document is created via an ionic angular app which then triggers a firebase function like below

```
exports.generateReadings = onDocumentCreated("sessions/{sessionId}", async (event) => {
    const snapshot = event.data;
    if (!snapshot) {
        console.log("No data associated with the event");
        return;
    }
    const data = snapshot.data();
    logger.log("Entire data is:", data)
```

This is working great. However, I want this function to trigger 5 minutes after the document is created. Is there a way to do that? I am trying to avoid keep running the function every 5 min as a schedule and do so as it will un-necessary run and waste resources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing built into `onDocumentCreated` to have it trigger after a certain interval, but you can build it yourself.

You can either have the function sleep for 5 minutes (with `setTimeout`) or [schedule a task](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/task-functions) at the right time. I'd probably pick the latter, as it means you won't be paying for CPU and memory usage during those 5 minutes of waiting.

Comment: yeah keeping it slept and eating resources is definitely not ideal. Let me look into schedule a task

Comment: Sleeping a cloud function with setTimeout is not a good idea.  It's costly and prone to error. Scheduled tasks are the right way to delay some work with CF.